# JDBC Columns not recognized

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, db2

I've been trying to make a login page and have run into a problem with pulling information from the database containing User credentials. When running the code I get the following error "Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=USERNAME, DRIVER=3.68.61" meaning (I think) that the column username cannot be located, but it is there. The table USERS contains the columns username, password, f_name, and l_name. The username and password for this application are collected via a JSP and passed to a servlet which in turn calls the following .java which has been passed both the username and password entered by the user:

```
public class Database {
public String lookup( String username, String password) throws SQLException {

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultset = null;

    String f_name = "";
    String query = "SELECT f_name FROM USERS WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Connecting to Database");
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://ipaddress:port/database name", "username", "userpassword");
        System.out.println("Connection Successful");


        statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, username);
        statement.setString(2, password);
        resultset = statement.executeQuery();

        if( resultset.next())
        {
            f_name = resultset.getString("f_name");
        }
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException error)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }

    catch ( SQLException error)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }

    finally
    {
        if( connection != null)
        {
            connection.close();
        }

        if( statement != null)
        {
            statement.close();
        }

        if( resultset != null)
        {
            resultset.close();
        }

    }//end finally

    return f_name;
}
}
```

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Actually, the column `f_name` was not found in table Users. Did you try to connect using any db2 client tool and execute this query?

Comment: Yes, I've been using Eclipse's Database plug-in. The select statement will work with an asterisk and no WHERE clause. So (SELECT * FROM USERS) works but (SELECT f_name FROM USERS) gives me error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=F_NAME, DRIVER=3.68.61 while (SELECT f_name FROM USERS WHERE username = 'whatever I choose') gives me the same error except SQLERRMC=USERNAME now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**42703** means  *An undefined column, attribute, or parameter name was detected.*

Here is the link with different DB2 error codes https://urssanj00.wordpress.com/2008/03/04/db2-sql-error-code-and-description/

Answer (score 0):

Could that be that you created your columns in lowercase? Try `select colname from syscat.columns where tabname = 'USERS'`. If the columns show in lowercase you'd have to quote them in every query: `select "f_name" from users where "username" = 'whatever'`.